# HTML: Image in title

Tags: html

I'm making a website and i want to put an image in header in title where's the name of website and how to do that?

Here's my code and in the title where'w MyName i don't know how to put a picture.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>MyName(PICTURE)</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="website.css"
</head>
```

http://bayimg.com/NApomAAfl (here's a picture of what i want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put an image in the title. Most sites use favicons to show an image in the tab of your browser.

Put this code in the `head` of your html file. Create a `favicon.png` file in the root of your web server:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="//favicon.png" />
```